# Overload Resolution Issue with overloaded generic method

Tags: generics, swift, overload-resolution

I do have an issue with an overloaded generic method. Consider this example:

```
class Foo {

    func foo<T>(v: T) {
        println("foo<T>(v: T)")
    }
    func foo<T>(x: Int, v: T) {
        println("foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)")
    }

}


let foo = Foo()
foo.foo("")
foo.foo(1, "")
foo.foo(x: 1, "")
foo.foo(x: 1, v: "")
```

This prints the following to the console:

> foo(v: T)
>   foo(v: T)
>   foo(v: T)
>   foo(v: T)

That is, no matter what, only the method `foo<T>(v: T)` will be selected from the overload resolution. Note: The compiler passes a tuple `(:Int, :String)` to the first method instead calling the second method.

Is this expected behavior?

Well, I doubt: I do concede that the type parameter can hold a tuple, however I would think that the function `foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)` is a better match.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a workaround. The generic method `foo<T>(v: T)` seems to fit everything through passing a tuple - no matter what other overloads exist.

### Update

In Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a), as opposed to *methods* (functions bound to a particular type) overloaded *functions*  do resolve as expected:

Consider this code snippet:

```
func foo<T>(o: T) {
    println("foo<T>(:T), \(o)")
}

func foo<T>(x: Int, o: T) {
    println("foo<T>(:Int, :T), \(x), \(o)")
}

foo(1)
foo(1, "a")
```

This prints the following to the console:

> foo(:T), 1
>    foo(:Int, :T), 1, a

This makes me believe that this is an issue in the compiler. I filed a bug report.

Comment: Re the edit: It’s not a bug in the compiler. Free functions in Swift default to anonymous arguments, whereas member functions default to named arguments. So it isn’t a bug (except in so much as you might think this is inconsistent and annoying, which is a reasonable position to take – it seems driven by the desire to make methods more like Objective-C). If you write your free function as `func foo<T>(x: Int, #o: T)` so it’s the same as your member function, you get the same behaviour.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks for the clarification. Yes, in _this_ case it's more the inconsistence that seems weird (at first glance) and which makes it difficult to intuitively _use_ a function or a method "properly". I understand the reasoning behind it, though, but it's just unfortunate that this has this effect. Additionally, when having a definition `func f<T>(x:Int, v:T)` I can't see why `f(1, "a")` selects `func<T>(e:T)` where T is a tuple `(:Int, :String)`. Wouldn't `func f<T>(x:Int, v:T)` be a better match?

Answer (score 1):

Try delete "x:" before the first parameter like:

```
foo.foo(1, v: "")
```

**UPDATED**

For **methods** the default behaviour is:

> Specifically, Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names both local and external parameter names by default.

For **functions**:

> If you want users of your function to provide parameter names when they call your function, define an external parameter name for each parameter, in addition to the local parameter name. You write an external parameter name before the local parameter name it supports, separated by a space: ...

And the documents also says in functions, that:

> If you provide an external parameter name for a parameter, that external name must always be used when you call the function.

It looks like this is true for methods, and that was the reason why `foo.foo(1, v: "")` worked only for methods, because there was an external parameter name, and you had to use that.

Comment: While this workaround does work for the given type signatures of the overloaded methods - it seems a bit brittle: for example, when changing `func foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)` to `foo<T>(x: Int, _ v: T)` the workaround breaks. It seems the issue is related to how the compiler packs arguments into a tuple. I'd hoped, there's something more reliable. Nonetheless, it's a workaround. ;)

Comment: Update: overloaded _free functions_ do resolve as expected. Please see my update.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I added a little update that might explain why your solution worked with functions, and mine with methods.

Answer (score 1):

Ha, yes that is pretty counterintuitive.  It seems specific to the case when you have a named second parameter that is generic vs an unnamed single generic parameter.

Some possible fixes:

Of course, the one case you didn’t try in your example is not naming `x` but naming `v`:

```
foo.foo(1, v: "") // prints foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)
```

Alternatively, if you ditch the named argument `v`:

```
class Foo {

    func foo<T>(v: T) {
        println("foo<T>(v: T)")
    }

    func foo<T>(x: Int, _ v: T) {
        println("foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)")
    }

}

let foo = Foo()
foo.foo("")     // prints foo<T>(v: T)
foo.foo(1, "")  // prints foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)
foo.foo(1, "")  // prints foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)
```

Humorously, this flips the one call that worked before to do the opposite:

```
foo.foo(1, v: "")  // prints foo<T>(v: T)
```

Alternatively, you could mandate argument names for *everything*:

```
class Foo {

    func foo<T>(#v: T) {
        println("foo<T>(v: T)")
    }

    func foo<T>(#x: Int, v: T) {
        println("foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)")
    }

}


let foo = Foo()
foo.foo(v: "")     // prints foo<T>(v: T)
foo.foo(x: 1, v: "")  // prints foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)
foo.foo(x: 1, v: "")  // prints foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)
foo.foo(x: 1, v: "")  // prints foo<T>(x: Int, v: T)
```

Comment: Explicit naming of parameters (mandate argument names) in both overloads seems to be the most safe approach. Not the "prettiest", though :/  Perhaps, when there were a chance to have a type constraint for `T` (e.g. `Streamable` in the example)- but in my actual code `T` really does not have a constraint.

Comment: Update: overloaded _free functions_ do resolve as expected. Please see my update.